# SQL Segmentation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

| Customer | Amount | Date | Period | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77766 | 50 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 2 |
| 77766 | 20 | 2022-03-31 | 2 | 2 |
| 77766 | 30 | 2022-04-30 | 3 | 3 |
| 12345 | 50 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 1 |
| 12345 | 20 | 2022-03-31 | 2 | 2 |
| 12345 | 30 | 2022-04-30 | 3 | 3 |

and I'm trying to achieve this segmentation model where I assign a Group to its corresponding Period per Customer

| Customer | Amount | Date | Period | Group | Group_Period1 | Group_Period2 | Group_Period3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77766 | 50 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 77766 | 20 | 2022-03-31 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 77766 | 30 | 2022-04-30 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 12345 | 50 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 12345 | 20 | 2022-03-31 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 12345 | 30 | 2022-04-30 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I tried case function but it didn't work

```
select a.*, 
case when a.Period=1 then Group end Grupo1 , 
case when a.Period=2 then Group2 end Grupo2 , 
case when a.Period=3 then Group3
end Grupo3 
from a
```

I got this output:

| Customer | Amount | Date | Period | Group | Group_Period1 | Group_Period2 | Group_Period3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77766 | 50 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 2 | 2 | null | null |
| 77766 | 20 | 2022-03-31 | 2 | 2 | null | 2 | null |
| 77766 | 30 | 2022-04-30 | 3 | 3 | null | null | 3 |
| 12345 | 50 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 1 | 1 | null | null |
| 12345 | 20 | 2022-03-31 | 2 | 2 | null | 2 | null |
| 12345 | 30 | 2022-04-30 | 3 | 3 | null | null | 3 |

Can anybody guide me to achieve the expected? Thank you in advice

Comment: Mysql <> SQL server - please correct your tags

Comment: `from dual` No such thing in SQL Server. This is oracle?

Comment: @SMor I suppose `MySQL8.0+`

Comment: You tried `SELECT ... FROM dual`, There is no reference to the table you have ("I have this table")   So, what did you REALLLY try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function such as `MAX() OVER ()` with conditionals for values of `Period` column such as

```sql
SELECT *, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Period=1 THEN `Group` END) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) AS Group_Period1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Period=2 THEN `Group` END) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) AS Group_Period2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Period=3 THEN `Group` END) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) AS Group_Period3
  FROM t -- replace with your table's name
```

where grouping is figured out through use of `PARTITION BY` clause

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d48f71b9ba4cdd2ddd8b1d02655beb72)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be via inline sub-query.

```
select *,
(select group_1 from cust a where a.customer = b.customer and period=1) Group_Period1,
(select group_1 from cust a where a.customer = b.customer and period=2) Group_Period2,
(select group_1 from cust a where a.customer = b.customer and period=3) Group_Period3 
from cust b;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d517968a1a1747b6178d205d693ba31)